# Show validation summary message for a few seconds in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show error with validation summary for a few seconds, for example show errors for 2 seconds, and hide validation summary div after that. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can easily handle your case. You can set time out, after the finish time out remove validation from form & hide the div.

Comment: how do i write it ? Please explain more @AsifRaza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible way to do this is to create a `<div class="validationSummary">You summary</div>`
and in your view place a script which will make value inside `validationSummary` disappear after given time, in your case 2 secs.

```
 @section Scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">  
setTimeout(function () { $('.validationSummary').fadeOut(); }, 2000);   
</script>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,Its Not worked in Section Scripts When I Remove it,it worked
Why?

Comment: You need to enable scripts in Views/Shared ´_Layout.cshtml´ by putting into <body> in this case ´@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)´ more about Sections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.1#sections